# Display large html content page wise in WebView

Tags: android

I have a large HTML which contents huge number of lines. But I want to 
show content of the HTML file that fits a 
single screen.

I want to provide a " > " button to show the next 
contents of the same HTML file.

I want to only display the HTML contents that fits the 
screen similar to eBook reader application. For user, it seems there are 
several pages.

Is there any way in which I can achieve this functionality. Whether 
WebView has any function related to full fill my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution for this?

Comment: if you get the  answer please update this answer ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017961/how-to-display-the-html-content-page-wise-using-webview-in-android/12035167#12035167

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this for a while and finally got the answer. Try this code inside onpagefinished() method.

```
int HeightWv,contentHts;

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            System.err.println("Find     Height->"+HeightWv);

            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(HeightWv==0){contentHts= 0;}
                    else if(HeightWv!=0){contentHts= HeightWv;}
                    HeightWv = wv.getHeight();
                    Log.e("1",""+ HeightWv);
                    HeightWv = HeightWv+contentHts;
                    Log.e("2",""+ HeightWv);
                    scrolpage();
                     }});
               Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(HeightWv==0){contentHts= 0;}
                    else if(HeightWv!=0){contentHts= HeightWv;}
                    HeightWv = wv.getHeight();
                    Log.e("3",""+ HeightWv);
                    HeightWv = contentHts-HeightWv;
                    Log.e("4",""+ HeightWv);
                    scrolpage();
                     }});
         }
        public void scrolpage(){
            wv.scrollTo(0, HeightWv);
            Log.e("scroll",""+ HeightWv);

        }
```